# Ordering of json objects after jolt transformation

Tags: json, jolt

**Input:**

```
{

//The input json object

}
```

**Desired Output**:

```
{

"Event1": "Value1",
"Event2": [
            // collection of json objects
          ],

"Event3": {
            //The input json object
          }

}
```

*So basically the input json goes in the "Event3" of another json object wrapper.*

**This is my Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "Event3"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "Event1": "Value1",
      "Event2": [
        // some objects
       ]
    }
  }
]
```

*Now the problem is - the above spec is doing the transformation, but ordering of the objects are messed up, like this:*

```
{
"Event3": {
            //The input json object
          },
          
"Event2": [
            // some objects
          ],
"Event1": "Value1"

}
```

Please suggest how should I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using another `shift` operation at the end to get them in the desired order.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "Event3"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "Event1": "Value1",
      "Event2": [
        "ob1", "obj2"
        ]
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Event1": "Event1",
      "Event2": "Event2",
      "Event3": "Event3"
    }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using the **sort** operation?

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Think that might do the trick for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering. A small problem though - sort will arrange them in alphabetical order of the attribute names; here in my case, the names I used - Event1, Event2 .. are just for representation. My actual json has different attribute names. Any way to set the order by specifying the attribute names?

Comment: Dont think so. From jolts git page: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Sortr.java "The sort order is standard alphabetical ascending".

Answer (score 1):

Add another shift operation and just copy paste each field from input json to output json.

```html
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "Event3"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "Event1": "Value1",
      "Event2": [
        "ob1", "obj2"
        ]
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Event1": "&", //same as "Event1":"Event1",
      "Event2": "&",
      "Event3": "&"
    }
    }
]
```