# Reordering of plain JSON by JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I'm a new in JOLT and need a help in a transformation.

Case is - adding key:value to the top of plain JSON, shifting other pairs down to bottom.

**Initial json**

```
{ "keyA":"valueA",
  "keyB":"valueB"}
```

**Jolt Specification**

```
[{"operation": "default",
  "spec": {
    "metaA": "metaValueA",
    "metaB": "metaValueB"
}}]
```

**Desired output**

```
{   "metaA": "metaValueA",
    "metaB": "metaValueB",
    "keyA": "valueA",
    "keyB": "valueB"}
```

**Real output**

```
{   "keyA": "valueA",
    "keyB": "valueB",
    "metaA": "metaValueA",
    "metaB": "metaValueB"}
```

[Similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171609/ordering-of-json-objects-after-jolt-transformation) gives not similar json in this case.

Thank all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although JSON objects are unordered by [definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-1).

It can be achieved by running a simple shift to change order:

```
[{
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "metaA": "metaValueA",
      "metaB": "metaValueB"
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "keyA": "&",
      "keyB": "&",
      "metaA": "&",
      "metaB": "&"
    }
 }]
```